# React panel is squashed in tab that is not directly loaded - React Equalizer

Tags: reactjs, tabs, redux, equalizer

I am using React, Redux and Bootstrap setup. I am building book website that have different tabs in that tabs are items(books) that have the same id through the different tabs. All my data is stored in a store and passed down to panel like so: TabsContainer(here I filter the books and pass down via props)->[All, Favorites, ...]->List of Books (all the same for every one) -> Book (all the same).

It is hard to post all the code and also basic concepts since I don't have idea what could be wrong. I instead post the result.

This is where it is ok. I can also fix the bug by resizing the window, but then it bugges the other 4 tabs.
[image]

This is clearly a bug. Bugg happens always when I move aways from inital tab.
[image]

What could be wrong? Should I set different keys? But if I understand correctly the react would do necessary rendering.

**Update** Found the root of the evil is the react Equalizer that I used to match column sizes (bootstrap responsive) so that button row appeared on the bot. I believe that has to do with incompatibility with React. **So the problem now is how to put button row on the bottom of the panel.**

```
 <div className="col-md-12 col-lg-6">
                <div className="panel panel-default no-padding">
                    <div className="panel-body contentRow" style={book_item.mainContainer}>
                        <Equalizer>
                            <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" style={book_item.imageContainer}>
                                <div>
                                    <FavoriteIcon reading={reading} style={book_item.favorites}
                                                  onFavoriteChanged={this.onFavoriteChanged}/>
                                    <Link to={"readings/"+reading.id+"/edit"} params={{id: reading.id}} style={book_item.imageLink}>
                                        <img
                                            src={'http://smartbooky.hopto.org/media/images/books/' + reading.book.id + '.jpg'}
                                            height="210px" style={book_item.bookImage}/>
                                    </Link>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" style={book_item.textContainer}>
                                <div className="bookTitle">
                                    <strong>{reading.book.title}</strong><br/>
                                </div>
                                <div className="bookSubtitle">
                                    {(() => {
                                        if (reading.book.subtitle)
                                            return (<div><em>{reading.book.subtitle}</em> <br/></div>);
                                    })()}
                                </div>
                                <div className="bookAuthors">
                                    <div>{authors ? authors : "Unknown author"}<br/></div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="bookDescription hidden-xs" style={book_item.bookDescription}>
                                    {truncatedDescription.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "")}
                                </div>
                                <div className="bookTags hidden-xs row" style={book_item.bookTags}>
                                    {reading.book.genre ? BookCard.renderTags(reading.book.genre) : void(0)}
                                </div>
                                <div className="buttonRow"
                                     style={window.innerHeight > 400 ? book_item.buttonRow : void(0)}>
                                    <div className="col-xs-4">
                                        <Button icon="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" name="Remove" kind="primary"
                                                handleClick={this.onReadingDelete} style={book_item.buttonRemove} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="col-xs-4">
                                        <Button icon="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list" name="Shelf" kind="primary"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="col-xs-4">
                                        <Button icon="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" name="Edit" kind="primary"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </Equalizer>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Is there an updated visual with this new realisation? Or has nothing changed visually?

Comment: I fixed the problem and It works as it should, but not with Equalizer. If anyone knows how to do it with it, let me know.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what equalizer is doing here but could you not set a max-width and min-width on these columns to help with consistency?

Comment: @connected_user I did something similar as you said. The Equalizer is used to match the column heights in case of 2 column item grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creator of `react-equalizer` here. It is possibly an issue with the equalization happening before the image is loaded. I just published a new verion that fixes this issue (1.0.5).

Here is a working example with `react-bootstrap` tabs:

http://jsbin.com/mayanakiqo/edit?js,output

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {

    let colStyles = {
      float: 'left',
      width: '50%',
      padding: '10px',
      background: '#ddd',
      border: '4px solid white',
      boxSizing: 'border-box'
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Tabs defaultActiveKey={2}>
          <Tab eventKey={1} title="Tab 1">
            <Equalizer byRow={false}>
              <div style={colStyles}>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" />
              </div>
              <div style={colStyles}>
                Test content
              </div>
            </Equalizer>
          </Tab>
          <Tab eventKey={2} title="Tab 2">
            <Equalizer byRow={false}>
              <div style={colStyles}>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" />
              </div>
              <div style={colStyles}>
                Test content
              </div>
            </Equalizer>
          </Tab>
          <Tab eventKey={3} title="Tab 3">
            <Equalizer byRow={false}>
              <div style={colStyles}>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" />
              </div>
              <div style={colStyles}>
                Test content
              </div>
            </Equalizer>
          </Tab>
        </Tabs>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The other option would be to use flexbox to equalize the heights see https://codepen.io/imohkay/pen/gpard for example however it will depend on what browsers you need to support.

Comment: Thank you for you attention, it works as it should now.

Answer (score 1):

I think before answering this there are some things we need to know:

**1.** Do these Bootstrap tabs implement some sort of non-React JavaScript in terms of switching between them? I know that Bootstrap not only provides CSS files for installation, but it also can provide some JavaScript too to use some of its components.

**2.** I am guessing that in the pictures you posted, you are navigating from the Favorites Tab, to the All tab? If so, what SHOULD the All tab show? (It is possible that it is actually rendering the intended elements, and it is just the css that is making it look wrong.)

**3.** If the top two points are not the source of the problem, then we will need to see some code, at least for the render functions of the components involved, as well as what their states look like.

Comment: 1.) I am using React-Bootstrap Tabs - Controlled (https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#tabs), that includes supported JS for React. 2.) ALL tabs hows all books, CSS is highly unlikable to be the problem. 3.) Will post tomorrow

Comment: @connected_user, answers shouldn't be questions.

Comment: I agree with but I must admit that every comment, question, note is helpful. In this case @connected_user make me think and I checked CSS when I realized that I used Equalizer in my code. So you got my thumb up for helping me.

Comment: @free-soul I am new to stack overflow and don't go on it much but regardless I don't really care, as long as I help someone